# flex yacc (bison) segmentation fault while building the parsing tree

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, segmentation-fault

I'm having a problem in logical operators

In my .y file i have:

```
expr: expr oper1 expr { $$=insert_expression($2, $1, $3); }
     | expr oper2 expr { $$=insert_expression($2, $1, $3); }
     ;
```

In my .l file i determined that oper1 and oper2 are:

```
"<" | ">" | "=" | "<>" | "<=" | ">=" { return oper1; }
"AND" | "OR" { return oper2; }
```

Then i have a structure to put the values in:

```
typedef struct _Expression
{
    char *oper;
    struct _Expression *ex1;
    struct _Expression *ex2;
} is_expression;
```

and put the values in:

```
is_expression* insert_expression(char* oper, is_expression *expr1, is_expression *expr2)
{
    is_expression* e = (is_expression*)malloc(sizeof(is_expression));

    e->ex1 = expr1;
    e->ex2 = expr2;
    e->oper = oper;

    return e;
}
```

and finally show them:

```
void show_expression(is_expression *e)
{
    show_expression(e->ex1);
    printf("%s", e->oper);
    show_expression(e->ex2);
}
```

but then i get a segmentation fault everytime i use a expr oper expr:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation Fault
```

Any ideas about what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You're missing a curly bracket in your first snippet.

Comment: to be clear, `| expr oper2 expr $$=insert_expression($2, $1, $3); }` should be `| expr oper2 expr { $$=insert_expression($2, $1, $3); }`

Comment: Sorry, copy&paste error :-( the original code has no curly brackets missing (at least in y file :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

```
void show_expression(is_expression *e)
{
    show_expression(e->ex1);
    printf("%s", e->oper);
    show_expression(e->ex2);
}
```

Recursion must have a way to terminate!

A big clue is that you have just one `printf` which prints the operator. But the tree has stuff in it other than just operators: namely, operands!

In your expression tree, these operands are leaf nodes. How are they represented? They probably have null pointers for `ex1` and `ex2`, right? (Hopefully not garbage: all your parser rules do `$$` to some value, right?)

Also, there must be much more to your yacc file than that. The rule for `expr` you have shown cannot exist by itself because it is not reducible to a sequence of terminal symbols.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't see the infinite recursion.

Comment: I just showed a snippet of the code because it is getting pretty big. The recursion exists in the snippet but not in the real code. Sorry for that

Comment: if i write: 
a = b
'a' is ex1
'b' is ex2
and '=' is oper

For each expression he will print it's value, which is 'a' and 'b' respectively

so no problems here

Answer (score 0):

The default type for all tokens is `int`. If you don't have

```
%union {
    char *oper1
    char *oper2
}
```

There will be problems. As it is, you are mixing pointers and ints. This causes you're program to attempt to access arbitrary memory, causing the segfault.

**Edit:**

Alright, then fire that thing up in gdb or my preferred [cgdb](http://cgdb.sourceforge.net/).

```
cgdb yourCompiledParser
> r (add necessary command line switches)
when it segfaults
> backtrace
```

That will get you the approximate location it's failing at, and show you where you need break points. For gdb/cgdb debugging tips, check out this [article](http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/).

Comment: @Nitrate I've added a section on debugging, so you can find what is causing the segfault.

Comment: i managed to trace the error at the second expr. if i change the rules to accept "expr : expr oper" it works

Comment: No. i need to have and 'expr oper expr' condition

Comment: if i write a = 0 i get "syntax error in 0" show_program(is=0x0), where show_program is the first call to print the tree. If i put a = b it says "syntax error in b" and so on... You get the point :-)

Comment: @Nitrate ah, that looks like a failure to end the parse tree. There is no condition that closes the parse recursion. `expr: expr opr expr` can recurse infinitely. You need a top level rule to stop, such as `expr: statement '\n'` or some such.

Comment: As i said before i didn't put all the grammar here because there's a lot more than what i've showed. I do have terminal rules for expression, such as expr: NUMBER and expr: REALNUMBER and others. So i don't know why this isn't working

Comment: @Nitrate so did you follow all the steps it takes when matching a single line? If you input only `a = b` and walk through the code, what happens?

Comment: Turns out i had a redefinition of "and" and "or" as operators AND and OR conflicting with 'oper2'

Answer (score 0):

In order to have sane values for `$n`, you need a `%union` directive to specify all the possible types, and then you need to use those types in `%token`/`%type` directives:

```
%union {
    is_expression  *exp;
    char           *str;
}

%token<str> oper1 oper2
%type<exp> expr
```

Then you ALSO need to make sure you set the values properly in your .l file:

```
"<" | ">" | "=" | "<>" | "<=" | ">=" { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return oper1; }
"AND" | "OR" { yylval.str = strdup(yytext); return oper2; }
```

Otherwise, you'll be passing random garbage as the first operand to `insert_expression`, and then crashing when you try to do anything with `oper` (as it points at random garbage)

Comment: Sorry, once again i skipped the union. In fact i added what you've suggested. Still SIGSEGV. I've ran out of ideas. Nothing seems to work